# Wifiに接続・未接続で処理を分岐したい

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui

よろしくお願い致します。
Monaca、onsen-uiを利用して、アプリを開発しています。

デバイスが、Wifiに接続した時と、
接続していない時で処理を分けたいのですが、
（通信量制限等を考慮した設計）
お分かりになる方いらっしゃいますでしょうか。
何卒よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

こちらの公式プラグインを利用することで、Wifiで接続しているか確認することができるようです。

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information

```
if(Connection.WIFI == navigator.connection.type){
  // WIFIで接続している
};
```

Wifiで接続された瞬間に処理を実行したい場合は、ネットワークがオンラインになったときに発生するイベントと組み合わせることで、恐らく実現可能です。

```
document.addEventListener("online", function(){
  if(Connection.WIFI == navigator.connection.type){
    // オンラインになったときにWIFIで接続していた時実行
  };      
}, false);
```